# Can't start old rails version (syntaxError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I just imported a 5 years old rails project on my ubuntu 18.04 server. I downloaded all the requirements such as ruby 2.0.0 or rails 3.2.22 and all the gems.

At the moment I'm trying to run: `rails app:update` which gives me the following error (the same when I run `rail s`) :

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require': /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/coverband-5.1.0/lib/coverband.rb:83: syntax error, unexpected '.' (SyntaxError)
    (Rake&.application&.top_level_tasks ...
           ^
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
        from /home/ project/apps/current/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I also get an error when I try to run: `rake migrate`

```
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/coverband-5.1.0/lib/coverb                                        and.rb:83: syntax error, unexpected '.'
    (Rake&.application&.top_level_tasks ...
           ^
/home/ project/apps/current/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ project/apps/current/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/ project/apps/current/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The gem `coverband v5.1.0` was [released on December 31st 2020](https://rubygems.org/gems/coverband/versions/5.1.0). So there is no way that this is a "5 year old application". You must either have not committed a `Gemfile.lock` (so had no record of what gem versions were actually being used?!), or have run `bundle update` - which updated a bunch of dependencies to something the old app wasn't prepared for.

Comment: You **MIGHT** be able to just use ruby `2.3` (which introduced the `&.` safe-navigation syntax) and find that thing works fine, or you might also encounter a bunch more problems as you've tried to update 5 years' worth of dependencies all in big go.

Comment: My advice, if you don't get this working quickly with ruby `2.3`, would be to start by reverting your change to the `Gemfile.lock` (i.e. run the old application exactly in the way it was previously used) and then only update smaller sets of dependencies at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safe navigation operator (`&.`) was added in Ruby 2.3.0.

Some of the code that changed by running `rails app:update` uses it.

Hence you first need to upgrade your Ruby version to 2.3.0+.

---

[Rails upgrades and Ruby version requirements](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#ruby-versions)